# Does "%" divide the length of the word? If so, why does only 'why' come up?

Tags: python, loops, division

I hope to turn this into an app to remind myself to think every once in a while. I would like to ask 'why'/'why not' every time I put an input in. I wanna make the determinant factor whether or not the length of the `notoriginal`/`alsonotoriginal` is even or odd.

```
print ('Have you thought today?') 

original = input('Yes or No:')

if len(original) > 2:
    notoriginal = input('When?:')

elif len(original) < 3:
    alsonotoriginal = input('Why?:')

while len(notoriginal) % 2 == 0:
    input('Why not?:') 

while len(notoriginal) % 2 > 0:
    input('Why?:')

while len(alsonotoriginal) % 2 == 0:
    input('Why not?:') 

while len(alsonotoriginal) % 2 > 0:
    input('Why?:')
```

You guys are the best! Thanks!

Edit: Thank you for all your help. I realize this was a pretty simple thing that I messed up. I'd also like to point out that I've since changed the original/notoriginal to better variable names such as second, third, and fourth. I fixed the problem I had, I took your suggestions. What I was confused/forgot about was that you could simply rename variables later in the code and the whole variable would change. What I had was  this:

```
print ('Have you thought today?') 

first = input('Yes or No:')

if len(*first*) > 2:
    **second** = input('When?:')

elif len(*second*) < 3:
    **third** = input('Why?:')

if len(third) % 2 == 0:
    fourth = input('Why not?:') 
else:
    fifth = input('Why?:')

while len(fourth) % 2 == 0:
    fifth = input('Why?')

while len(fourth) % 2 > 0:
    sixth = input('Why not?')
```

The problem was that I kept renaming variables, when they didn't have to be renamed and in fact caused an error because they were renamed. I was calling on the code to assess two separate variables when I should've been calling the code to check on a single variable that had two separate outcome values, like so:

```
print ('Have you thought today?') 

first = input('Yes or No:')

if len(first) > 2:
    second = input('When?:')

elif len(first) < 3:
    second = input('Why?:')

if len(second) % 2 == 0:
    third = input('Why not?:') 
else:
    third = input('Why?:')

while len(third) % 2 == 0:
    third = input('Why?')

while len(third) % 2 > 0:
    third = input('Why not?')
```

Comment: You have bugs. About half way through your program you stop assigning the return value of the input() function to a variable. That input is dropped and since the loop variable doesn't change, you are stuck. Consider adding print statements to debug when stuck on a problem like this!

Answer (score 2):

### The % Operand

> The % (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the
>   first argument by the second. The numeric arguments are first
>   converted to a common type. A zero right argument raises the
>   ZeroDivisionError exception. The arguments may be floating point
>   numbers, e.g., 3.14%0.7 equals 0.34 (since 3.14 equals 4*0.7 + 0.34.)
>   The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its
>   second operand (or zero); the absolute value of the result is strictly
>   smaller than the absolute value of the second operand

[taken from here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)

To divide `len('word')` you can use the `/` operand, but by using the `% 2` operation you are able to determine if a number is even or not by analyzing the result, if it returns 0, it is even, if it does not, it is odd, like so:

```
number = input('Type a number: ')

if number % 2 == 0:
    print('Even')
else:
    print('Odd')
```

---

### Why the 'why' input keeps coming up

The reason your code loops and seems to get stuck on the 'why?' question is because you are using `while len(notoriginal) % 2 > 0` and `while len(alsonotoriginal) % 2 > 0`, since the `notoriginal` and the `alsonotoriginal` values don't change after the input, you get what is called a 'infinite loop',  the same `while` loop will run forever. To fix this, instead of using `while`, you could use a `if` and `elif` statement, but doing so will require you to fix your code logic, since it's quite flawed at the moment.

---

### Also...

Don't ever call your variables these generic names, it just makes for very confusing debugging later on.